# Button in gridview yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I've create button view profile at gridview. When user click the button view profile, it will go to profile based on user_id. Here is the code.

```
      <?= GridView::widget([
 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
 'id' => 'mygrid',
 'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    'user_id',
    'project_name',
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    [
        'label' => 'View Profile',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'content' => function($model) {
            return Html::a('View', ['projectstudent/viewprofile', 'id' =>     $model->user_id],
                ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
        }
    ],
]
 ]); ?>
```

At controller

```
    public function actionViewprofile($id)
{
 return $this->render('profile', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

The requested page is not found. How can i fix the code? Thanks.

Comment: Is controller named `ProjectstudentController`?

Comment: yup  @Bizley . The controller is Projectstudentcontroller.

Comment: There might be several reasons: controller might be called in wrong way (be inside a module), UrlManager or server url rewriting rules might be wrong, on non-Windows environments file name case might be wrong... There is not enough information from you to tell for sure.

Comment: Update your question and show your controller  code ..

Comment: can you open your url directly in browser??? as same as localhost/projectstudent/viewprofile?id=1

Answer (score 0):

Here may be problem of controller name that u are specified, there is no need to define controller name if you want to call the action of same controller.

So replace so your code with this and try again

```
 return Html::a('View', ['viewprofile', 'id' =>$model->user_id],
            ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
```